# Angular/TypeScript Map using last index on every object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, indexing

I'm trying to create an array of 120 objects (hex's for a map) and then add info to each one.

When I use map the id is supposed to be the index of the current object and I can console log the correct, current index as expected but for some reason EVERY object has an id of 119. I've looked at some of the other map examples on here and with Mozilla and I'm not understanding where I'm going wrong.

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  arrayOfObjects = Array(120).fill({})
  hexTiles = this.arrayOfObjects.map( (hex, index) => this.createHex(hex, index))

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  createHex(hex, index){
    console.log('Current Index', index)
    hex['id'] = index
    hex['x-coordinate'] = null
    hex['y-coordinate'] = null
    hex['mapped'] = false
    hex['terrain'] = ''
    hex['details'] = ''

    return hex
  }

}
```

***UPDATE***
I have tried a suggested solution but am now getting an array of 120 empty objects. 
Here is the updated code:

HTML: This displays nothing.

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let hex of hexTiles; let i = index">
    <pre>
      {{hex}}
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS: This will console log "Hexs (120) [empty × 120]"

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  hexTiles = [...Array(120)].map((_, i) => this.createHex({}, i));


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Hexs', this.hexTiles);
  }

  createHex(hex, index) {
    hex['id'] = index;
    hex['x-coordinate'] = null;
    hex['y-coordinate'] = null;
    hex['mapped'] = false;
    hex['terrain'] = '';
    hex['details'] = '';
    return hex;
  }

}
```

Comment: You can simplify `this.arrayOfObjects.map( (hex, index) => this.createHex(hex, index))` to just `this.arrayOfObjects.map(this.createHex)`, not sure if this will fix your plroblem.

Comment: @gv0000, I updated my answer to fix the [...Array(120)] problem, sorry for that. hexTiles = Array.from({ length: 120 }).map((_, i) => this.createHex({}, i)); should work, but your methods works too, just don't use the array content in the map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
arrayOfObjects = Array(120).fill({})
hexTiles = this.arrayOfObjects.map( (hex, index) => this.createHex(hex, index))
```

for this

```
hexTiles = [...Array(120)].map((_, i) => this.createHex({}, i));
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
function createHex(hex, index) {
    hex['id'] = index;
    hex['x-coordinate'] = null;
    hex['y-coordinate'] = null;
    hex['mapped'] = false;
    hex['terrain'] = '';
    hex['details'] = '';
    return hex;
}

const hexTiles = [...Array(120)].map((_, i) => createHex({}, i));

console.log(hexTiles);
```

Here is an **explanation** of your problem.

```js
function createHex(hex, index) {
    hex['id'] = index;
    hex['x-coordinate'] = null;
    hex['y-coordinate'] = null;
    hex['mapped'] = false;
    hex['terrain'] = '';
    hex['details'] = '';
    return hex;
}
const obj = { };
const arrayOfObjects = Array(120).fill(obj);
const hexTilesBad = arrayOfObjects.map((hex, index) => createHex(hex, index));
console.log(obj)
```

When filling the array with {}, you are actually filling it with copies of the reference to the same object. This is because, by default, in Javascript/Typescript, when you assign an object, you assign its reference.

In the above example, instead of filling the array with `{}`, we fill it with `obj`, which is just `{}`. When we `console.log(obj)` at the end, we see that it indeed has the value of the last iteration.

Its reference has been copied 120 times in the array, and those references got passed to the `map`, then to your `createHex` function. So ultimately, you are just modifying 120 times the same object.

However, when you pass `{}` directly to `createHex` from the `map` arrow function, a new object is created for each iteration in the function scope, so nothing is shared.

**EDIT:**
`[...Array(120)]` does not seem to work in TypeScript. As pointed out by @AJT_82 in the comments below, this is due to a [TypeScript bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856) which causes this spread operator trick to incorrectly translate to JavaScript.

To circumvent the problem, you can try the following:

```
Array.from({ length: 120 })
```

or stick with your method

```
Array(120).fill({})
```

What is important is to not use the content of this array, since they are just references to the same object.

Comment: Why does this work, and not what OP is doing in question? Explanations are always good :)

Comment: Yes absolutely, I am updating the answer with another example

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately when I tried this I'm getting this error: "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" I think it might have something to do with this being an angular app and its lifecycle.

Comment: This is weird, as your function is setting the property id and to reading it. Do you have more detail?

Comment: Not really, I don't have much more code than what I pasted, as this is the first part I was working on but I can just update and all the relevant code.

Comment: It should not be related to lifecycle methods as you are not depending on any data from your view or angular and everything is run at construction time. Would you mind sharing a Stackblitz?

Comment: @jo_va I got real interested why `[...Array(120)]` didn't work, apparently this is a TS bug... from ages ago. Weird that it hasn't been fixed?! If you want to expand your answer by saying it's a bug, here's the link as reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856 :)

Comment: @AJT_82, sure I will, thank you for the information! This is a problem I also had in the past, but I never took the time to research it.